# What cases will prevent javascript from being executed in a WPF WebBrowser control?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

We have a System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control rendering HTML with references to jQuery (retrieved with https connection). Our test machine recently had its Internet Explorer version upgraded to 8.0.7600.16385. After the upgrade, the WebBrowser control stopped executing javascript. We tested the same HTML in a regular browser and also in a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control and it works perfectly in both.

Does anybody know what could cause?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to security restrictions. Try to include a [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on your page. For instance, this comment will tell the `WebBrowser` to execute the page with the security policy of the Local Intranet zone:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

Comment: I never knew about MOTW before I read your answer... but I should point out that the doco says you cannot use it to *elevate* your privileges, and this seems to be what you are suggesting?

Comment: @slugster, no, it doesn't cause an elevation of privilege. I don't know exactly how it works, I just know that I used it once in a similar scenario, and it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Typically the cause for "JavaScript doesn't execute" is the browser errors while parsing or executing it: file doesn't exist, file has syntax error in it, script threw an exception while running, etc.  You've attempted to rule this out by testing in a regular browser, but is there anything in the script that detects a UserAgent or browser features, and fails?  Can you harvest console errors from a WPF WebBrowser control?